# How can I determine the current exception in a catch (...) block?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining exception type after the exception is caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561997/determining-exception-type-after-the-exception-is-caught)

Following up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561997/determining-exception-type-after-the-exception-is-caught) , I'd like to print out the current exception in a **catch(...)** block -- just for logging. One answer there says that there is no standard way of doing this, but I don't like taking no for an answer :-)

**current_exception()** is a function mentioned in various places on the web but apparently not well-supported. Any thoughts on this? After all, even C has **errno**.

Because it can be rethrown (with a simple **throw*), the exception object must be available  somehow.

I am using MSVS 9.0.

Edit: The conclusion seems to be that this is not possible.

Comment: I don't see how this question is different than the one you referenced. Just because you don't like the answer is no reason to ask again.

Comment: I agree with Mark. But, maybe you don't realize, that you can use the accepted's answer's technique to catch the base classes of all common exceptions, like catching std::exception& and MFC's which can be caught as CException*.

Comment: The question is a bit different: The other one asks about identifying the exception's type, whereas this one wants to print as much information as possible about the exception.

Answer (score 8):

If you only care about exceptions that you know about when you're writing the code then you can write a handler that can deal with all 'known' exceptions. The trick is to rethrow the exception that you caught with `catch(...)` and then catch the various known exceptions...

So, something like:

```
try
{
 ...
}
catch(...)
{
   if (!LogKnownException())
   {
      cerr << "unknown exception" << endl;
   }
}
```

where `LogKnownException()` looks something like this:

```
bool LogKnownException()
{
   try
   {
      throw;
   }
   catch (const CMyException1 &e)
   {
      cerr << "caught a CMyException: " << e << endl;

      return true;
   }
   catch (const Blah &e)
   {
      ...
   }
   ... etc

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Determine what exceptions can be thrown and use a set of catch handlers to catch a set of common base types that covers them all.

---

As for getting the exception object from catch(...), it can't be done portably and as far as I know, it can't be done at all using the Microsoft compiler or gcc. What makes you think the exception object still exists in a catch(...) handler anyway?

Comment: >" What makes you think the exception object still exists in a catch(...) handler anyway?"


Because it can be rethrown (with a simple "throw"), the object must be there somewhere.

Comment: If the catch(...) is the top level catch handler? The as-if rule would entitle the compiler to destroy the object whenever is/was convenient. I doubt that happens in practice though.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on RTTI and use typeOf function. `current_exception` is purely stl function, and applies to stl exceptions only.
As a recommendation, use different `catch(exctype)` per exception type. This will make life a lot easier.

Comment: `catch(...)` doesn't give you an object to reference, so you can't know the type. And does RTTI work on POD types, such as int?

Answer (score 0):

Like alemjerus already said: current_exception works only for stl exceptions.
To get various stl errors you could also write:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception> //ecxeption (base class)
#include <new>       //bad_alloc
#include <typeinfo>  //bad_cast und bad_typeid
#include <ios>       //ios_base::failure    

...

try
{
  ...
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
  cerr<<"Error: "<<e.what()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: This is not true. std::current_exception works with any exception type.