# std::shared_ptr: Custom deleter not being invoked

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm working through C++ Primer, 5th edition, and the author has presented an example to do with using `shared_ptr`s to manage resources from older libraries that could leak memory, to prevent them from doing so.  I decided to create a test to see how it works, but my custom deleter doesn't get called after the exception is thrown and (deliberately) not caught:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct Connection {};

Connection* Connect(std::string host)
{
    std::cout << "Connecting to " << host << std::endl;
    return new Connection;
}

void Disconnect(Connection* connection)
{
    std::cout << "Disconnected" << std::endl;
    delete connection;
}

void EndConnection(Connection* connection)
{
    std::cerr << "Calling disconnect." << std::endl << std::flush;
    Disconnect(connection);
}

void AttemptLeak()
{
    Connection* c = Connect("www.google.co.uk");
    std::shared_ptr<Connection> connection(c, EndConnection);

    // Intentionally let the exception bubble up.
    throw;
}

int main()
{
    AttemptLeak();

    return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output:

> Connecting to www.google.co.uk

My understanding is that when a function is exited, whether that's exiting normally or because of an exception, the local variables will all be destroyed.  In this case, that should mean `connection` being destroyed when `AttemptLeaks()` exits, invoking its destructor, which should then call `EndConnection()`.  Notice also that I'm using, and flushing, `cerr`, but that also didn't give any output.

Is there something wrong with my example, or my understanding?

**Edit**: While I already have the answer to this question, for anyone else that stumbles upon this in the future, my problem was with my understanding of how `throw` works.  Although the answers below correctly state how to use it, I think it's best to explicitly make it clear that I was (incorrectly) trying to use it to 'generate' an unhandled exception, to test my code above.

Comment: Always catch exceptions _somewhere_

Comment: @MooingDuck I know.  I'm _intentionally_ not catching it, as the question states, to see _how_ it behaves, and it's not behaving how the author says it should.

Comment: as the answer below states, you have a correct understanding of shared_ptr and destructors, the error in your understanding is that of _exceptions_.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for verifying my understanding.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bare `throw` is intended for use inside catch blocks to rethrow a caught exception. If you use it outside a catch block, `terminate()` will be called and your program ends at once. See [what does "throw;" outside a catch block do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692065/what-does-throw-outside-a-catch-block-do)

If you delete the `throw`-statement the `shared_ptr` `connection` will go out of scope and should call the deleter. If you have any doubts about the exception-safety of using a shared_ptr (I don't ;),  you can explicitly throw an exception here by changing `throw` to `throw 1`.

Comment: I understand it's to be used with `catch` blocks.  The example presented in the book is saying that by specifying a custom deleter, like in this example, I can have that memory cleaned up automatically in case an unhandled exception occurs between when the memory is allocated and when it should be deleted.

Comment: @JohnH: I don't think you understand. `throw` by itself is used WITHIN a `catch` block to RE-throw the caught exception.  You have nothing here to re-throw.

Comment: There is no `catch` in your code and `terminate()` ends the program abruptly without an expection being thrown at all. Please read the referenced stack overflow question "what does 'throw' outside a catch block do".

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean from the linked answer now. `If throw; is executed when an exception is not active, it calls terminate() (§15.1/8).`  That might be it.

Comment: I already knew it worked correctly when `throw` wasn't specified, but I wanted to specifically test this when an exception occurred, just so I could see it for myself.  I just tried stuffing a random function call in `AttemptLeak()`, which could throw an exception, and made it do so.  After catching that exception, the deleter was invoked properly.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @PeterG. Concerning what happens when no handler is found
(§15.3/9): "If no matching handler is found, the function
std::terminate() is called; whether or not the stack is unwound
before this call to std::terminate() is implementation-defined".
So you can't make any bets one way or the other (except by
reading the documentation of the implementation).

Comment: @PeterG. I don't think the "no matching handler case" applies to a throw encountered when there is no active exception. The relevant sections are §15.1/9 and §15.5.1/2. Stack unwinding will *never* take place in this situation.

Comment: @Praetorian I hadn't noticed that he hadn't provided an argument
to the throw.  In that case, `std::terminate` _will_ be called
before stack unwinding.  Or rather, there won't be any stack
unwinding, because the `throw` itself doesn't take place.

Answer (score 3):

The [`throw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) expression without an operand is intended for rethrowing the exception being currently handled. If no exception is being handled then [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) is called. In this situation stack unwinding does not take place, which is why the deleter is never being called. Change your code to the folowing:

```
void AttemptLeak()
{
    Connection* c = Connect("www.google.co.uk");
    std::shared_ptr<Connection> connection(c, EndConnection);

    // Intentionally let the exception bubble up.
    throw 42; // or preferably something defined in <stdexcept>
}

int main()
{
    try {
        AttemptLeak();
    } catch(...) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the deleter will be called when the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative to my comment on Peter's answer.  This works as well.