# To understand the type of exception using try/catch in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, try-catch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining exception type after the exception is caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561997/determining-exception-type-after-the-exception-is-caught)

I am aware of exception handling in C#:

```
try{
// code causing exception
}
catch(System.Exception e){
// Here e variable holds the information about the actual exception that has occured in try block.
}
```

But, i want to achieve samething in VC++ (on VS 2008). 
How do we capture the **TYPE of exception that has occured in the try block in VC++**, as we don't have concept of packages in VC++?

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561997/determining-exception-type-after-the-exception-is-caught
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no a single base class for all exceptions in c++, so the only option, is specify what you want to handle

```
try
{
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
}
catch (const my_base_exception& e)
{
}
catch (const some_library_base_exception& e)
{
}
catch (...)
{
// ups something unknown
}
```

Bear in mind though, that if your `my_base_exception` is derived from `std::exception`, it will be intercepted by `catch (const std::exception& e)`, so swap these two catches if that's the case. the same goes for `some_library_base_exception`

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you generally *specify* the type that the `catch` can catch, instead of checking the type.

If you want to log the most derived type of a caught `std::exception`, then you can get that information via `typeid`, since `std::exception` is a polymorphic type.

If you're interested in logging types of exceptions outside of the standard exception type hierarhcy, then a good way is to catch generically (using `...`) and call a common rethrower function that knows of the possible non-standard exceptions and rethrows and `catch`es those. This centralizes the logic. But most likely your question is not about this somewhat advanced and rare technique (only relevant for use of non-well-behaved libraries), but rather, a simple misconception about exception handling in C++, for which the answer is, specify the relevant type that you're prepared to catch, in each `catch` clause.