# How to determine the cause of error when using C++ standard library functions?

Tags: c++

For example, in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt), it says `operator>>(std::basic_string)` can throw exceptions on these conditions.

> 2. may throw std::ios_base::failure if no characters are extracted
>    from is (e.g the stream is at end of file, or consists of whitespace
>    only), or if an exception is thrown during input.

But how can I know what really cause that exception, like ENOMEM, EINTR in C style errno? Does `std::ios_base::failure::what` and `std::ios_base::failure::code` tell me that? If it is, where can I find documentation about what exact error code is set in what exact situation? For instance, I want something like [POSIX documentation on `scanf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/scanf.html), which contains a list of error numbers and corresponding error conditions.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/562465/15559606) help? Otherwise you can just use `std::exception::what` which describes the exception. There also exists `typeid(exc).name()` but it's platform specific